# Delete empty values from a list but the element with index 0

Tags: python-3.x

**Python 3**

I'd like to delete all empty values from a list but the element with index 0.
In other words let's have two lists:

```
[1, "screen", "keyboard", "mouse", , , , "router", , ,]
[, "ball", "dumbbell", "bar-bell", , , , "sneakers"]
```

The result should be:

```
[1, "screen", "keyboard", "mouse", "router"]
[, "ball", "dumbbell", "bar-bell", "sneakers"]
```

Now I'm trying to implement a filter:

```
def delete_empty_values(a_list):
    return list(filter(None, a_list))
```

But this filter deletes everything including the element 0.

Well, using filters is not a dogma. Could you help me with the most pythonyc way to achieve what is planned?

Comment: If I paste those lists to my python console, I get a SyntaxError...

Comment: `''` is an empty value, show valid lists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a couple of ways:

```
[] if not a_list else [a_list[0], *filter(None, a_list[1:])]

[e for i, e in enumerate(a_list) if not (e is None and i)]
```